# Conditional Select in angular2-json-schema-form

Tags: json, angular, jsonschema

I want to show hide things based on what user picks in the select box.

For example,

I have 5 options to show in select. I selected option 1, which should should another component which is related to option 1. Like say is statement in option 1 correct? Yes or No. I am right now able to make it work like below. I will have lot of such use-cases, Is there an better way of handling it?

```
  "condition": {
"functionBody": 
   "try { return model.MultiSelect.indexOf('India')>=0 } 
    catch(e){return false}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should leverage *visibleIf* property.
As described in [README.md](https://github.com/makinacorpus/angular2-schema-form#conditional-fields):

> It is possible to make the presence of a field depends on another
>   field's value. To achieve this you just have to add a visibleIf
>   property to a field's definition. Adding the value $ANY$ to the array
>   of conditional values,will make the field visible for any value
>   inserted.

And the example given there (note the visibleIf in registerEmail email field which is similar to your case):

```
@Component({
  selector: "minimal-app",
  template: '<sf-form [schema]="mySchema"></sf-form>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  mySchema = {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Username"
      },
      "comment": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Comment"
      },
      "registerNewsletter": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "description": "I want to receive the newsletter",
        "default": false,
        "visibleIf": {
          "comment": ['$ANY$']
        }
      },
      "registerEmail": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "Email",
        "format": "email",
        // Declare that this field must be displayed only if registerNewsletter is true
        "visibleIf": {
          "registerNewsletter": [true]
        }
      }
    },
    "required": ["name", "comment", "registerToNewsletter"]
  }
}
```